# CSS not working in Devise(Rails) Mailer for Gmail

Tags: html, css, ruby-on-rails, devise, actionmailer

I send confirmation email after user signs up. I use devise's mailer view.
It seems like everything else is working, but CSS for `CONFIRM ACCOUNT` is not called at all. I read that I cannot use CSS classes for mailer view so I styled everything in inline style. When I view the mailer view on my web app, it looks great like below

[image]

But in actual mailer view it looks like this:

[image]

Below is the code what I have:

```
<body style="background-color: #F7F7F7;">
<div class="main wrapper clearfix">
    <div style="border: 1px solid #e4e4e4;
        border-radius: 5px;
        margin: 50px auto;
        padding: 20px 50px;
        box-shadow: 0 1px 5px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
        background-color: white;
        max-width: 700px;">
        <div style="text-align:center">
            <%= image_tag("logo-green.svg") %>
        </div><br><br>
        <div>
            <p>Welcome <%= @user.first_name %>!</p>

            <p style="line-height: 1.5">Let's confirm your email address. Click the button below to confirm your email.</p>

            <%= link_to 'CONFIRM ACCOUNT',
            confirmation_url(@resource, confirmation_token: @token),
            style: "font-family: Raleway-SemiBold, sans-serif;
                -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
                display: inline-block;
                cursor: pointer;
                text-decoration: none;
                color: white;
                letter-spacing: 1px;
                    padding: 13px 30px;
                    font-size: 0.8em;
                    color: #fff;
                    background-color: #00BA9B;
                    transition: box-shadow 0.2s cubic-bezier(0.4, 0, 0.2, 1);
                    transition-delay: 0.2s;
                    box-shadow: 0 2px 8px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.26);
                    margin-top: 25px;
                    margin-bottom: 20px;
                    border-radius:" %>

            <br><br>
            <p style="line-height: 1.5">Thanks,<br>website <br> <a href="www.website.com" style="color: #00BA9B; text-decoration:none">www.website.com</a></p>
            <br>

             <p style="color:grey; font-size:11px;">P.S. If you didn't sign up for website, please ignore this email - apologies for the disturbance.<p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
```

Styling on `<a href="www.website.com" style="color: #00BA9B; text-decoration:none">www.website.com</a>` works fine on mailer view. But in line styling on `CONFIRM ACCOUNT` does not work.
I would love to know why inline styling is working else where but not on `link_to 'CONFIRM ACCOUNT',`.

Answer (score 3):

There are a lot of limitations to email client HTML. [This guide shows you what you can and cannot do with email HTML.](http://templates.mailchimp.com/resources/email-client-css-support)

All those transitions, custom cursor, shadows? That won't fly.